# Q# (Quantum SDK) Canon.dll error

Tags: q#

I tried to run one of the examples of the new Quantum SDK
However, I didn't even manage to run the basic one like TeleportationSample, 
since the error: `QS1001 Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.dll not found` is displayed.

Other errors:

```
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\AmplitudeAmplification\AmplitudeAmplification.qs(421,40,421,43): error CS1001: Identifier expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\AmplitudeAmplification\AmplitudeAmplification.qs(421,40,421,43): error CS1002: ; expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\obj\qsharp\src\Math\Constants.g.cs(33,35,33,36): error CS1002: ; expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\obj\qsharp\src\Math\Constants.g.cs(33,35,33,36): error CS1513: } expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\RandomWalk.qs(81,39,81,57): error CS1001: Identifier expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\RandomWalk.qs(81,39,81,57): error CS1002: ; expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\RandomWalk.qs(82,40,82,58): error CS1001: Identifier expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\RandomWalk.qs(82,40,82,58): error CS1002: ; expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\Robust.qs(37,35,37,37): error CS1001: Identifier expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\Robust.qs(37,35,37,37): error CS1002: ; expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\Robust.qs(38,34,38,36): error CS1001: Identifier expected
1>J:\Users\Markus\Programming\Samples\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\PhaseEstimation\Robust.qs(38,34,38,36): error CS1002: ; expected
```

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this [Change Region](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989)

and set your region to English(USA).
The Problem is related to the numeric format of your region.